# Image does not show on leading part of list tile when using Circle Avatar and back ground image

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building this app and just have a small UI problem. I am using a `ListView` builder. On the leading part of the tile, I want a circular icon to display with the desired image.

I believe my implementation is correct but when I run my code the circle avatar does come out on the leading part of the tile but it does not display the desired image. Instead, it just shows a blue circle on the leading end of each tile.

I am also getting an exception from the terminal. I will attach my code and the exception that I am getting. I would really appreciate suggestions from anyone. Thank you all!

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    
      List<String> titles = ["Covid-19 Cases", "Covid-19 Vaccine Tracker",
        "Dr. John Campbell Youtube Channel", "Medcram YouTube Channel"];
    
      List<String> files = ["cases.png", "vaccineIMG.png", "dr.johncampbell.png",
          "Medcram.png"];
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
              title: Text("Your Covid-19 Briefing"),
            ),
            body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: titles.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      _launchUrl(index);
                    },
                    title: Text(
                      titles[index],
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        letterSpacing: 1.0,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/${files[index]}'),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
    
      _launchUrl(index) async {
        List<String> _urlsToLaunch = [
          "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/",
          "https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/science/coronavirus-vaccine-tracker.html",
          "https://www.youtube.com/c/Campbellteaching/videos/",
          "https://www.youtube.com/c/Medcram/videos"
        ];
    
          if (await canLaunch(_urlsToLaunch[index])) {
            await launch(_urlsToLaunch[index]);
          } else {
            throw "Could not open $_urlsToLaunch";
          }
      }
    }
```

Error:

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/cases.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:664:31)
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:648:14)
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:501:13)
...
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/cases.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#e7274(), name: "assets/cases.png", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
Unable to load asset: assets/vaccineIMG.png
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
Unable to load asset: assets/dr.johncampbell.png
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
Unable to load asset: assets/Medcram.png
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

`pubspec.yaml` file:

```
name: coronavirus_news_updates
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  url_launcher: ^5.4.11


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: Please include your `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: You need to add your assets to your `pubspec` file in order to use them. Check this for more info: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included your assets in your pubspec.yaml file?

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/your_image_name.png
```

or to incude the entire folder:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

Comment: I have not. I would need to do this for each of the images?

Comment: No. just use the second option I listed to include the entire assets folder if they are all including within the same directory.

Comment: This was the answer thank you. Will accept as soon as the site allows me to.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Good luck with the rest of development.